Flashback Logs Not Deleted With PDB Drop
There is a known issue with Oracle where the flashback logs are not reclaimable when a PDB is dropped and a restore point exists in the PDB.
I can see a restore point in x$kccrsp but no restore points exist in v$restore_point.  I believe I am experiencing the aforementioned issue but the Oracle support web site is "experiencing an unscheduled outage" and I was wondering if anyone knows of a solution for removing the errant restore point.

In case anyone else has this issue in the future, I decided to recreate the control file (using the NORESETLOGS option) and bounce the database (with flashback off).  That cleared out the errant restore point and orphaned all the old flashback logs.  I was able to delete all the old flashback logs from the OS with no issues.
This, unfortunately, resulted in the loss of the flashback, but that was not issue in this case.  The more important loss was the removal of the previous database incarnations.  In this case, the previous incarnations were not important, but this could be an important downside to this solution.
I did not want to wait on the Oracle support website to come back up because the FRA was filling up with flashback logs and a solution was needed.  Because the flashback logs were all unreclaimable, none of the typical solutions would work.  Perhaps there is a more elegant solution to be had.
